# Connect DDEV database to TYPO3 project

Tags: typo3, ddev

Im new to TYPO3 v13, i use typo3 with ddev I created my database.
I look arround i find nothing to connect te database or the docs are so old.
ChatGPT say i can connect it in the install.php site in my typo projekt so i open the install backend and there is nothing with database.

I don't know how to use it, i need 2 min to fetch the data via python, and 4 hours of research the internet and dont get it.
I want to use the data of my database in typo3 so i can add and remove data and show data on the page.

Comment: Do you want to connect a new blank database to the project or an existing database with data from an existing project?

Comment: i want just want to connect a blank database

Comment: DDEV brings it own database system and in the setup process (see my answer) it will be created automatically.

Answer (score 1):

For a basic TYPO3 setup with DDEV you should follow the official docs: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/Installation/TutorialDdev.html#installation-ddev-tutorial

DDEV's docs also explain a basic TYPO3 install: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#typo3

`ddev describe` will always show you how to access the database from inside the container. host=`db`, database=`db`, user=`db`, password=`db`.

The [DDEV FAQ](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/faq/#how-can-i-connect-to-my-database) explains how to connect to the database.

And the [Database Management](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/database-management/) article should help you as well.

Comment: I already done that but that is not the problem now i want to use the data in the data base in my projekt, like render it etc. I done every step and my database work fine, but there is nothin how to use the database.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but it's not clear to me yet: You want to transfer a database with all content to a web server with an own database?

Comment: No, maybe im stupid but, i want to have a database(ddev) i already created that, and put one line of test data in this. Now i have the database i can see it in my browser. But i dont know how to do anything with that data in my typo3 project. I want to Read and write the data to this. But i think i need a connection from typo3 to ddev and i dont know where i can configure a databse connection in my typo3 project to read / write etc.

Comment: If you can login into the TYPO3 backend, your databse is connected. So the question is if your whole setup and configuration are sufficient to show you the backend. Existing data you can just import with "ddev import-db --file=/path/to/your/file.sql".
Connecting the database is described already as an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78007652/1019850

Answer (score 1):

if you install the typo3 by hand (or better by composer), you can add the database connection in:
config/system/settings.php

```
'DB' => [
    'Connections' => [
        'Default' => [
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'dbname' => 'db',
            'driver' => 'mysqli',
            'host' => 'db',
            'password' => 'db',
            'port' => 3306,
            'tableoptions' => [
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collate' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            ],
            'user' => 'db',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: and how the get the data, sorry im complete new to typo3 i mean how to i use it

Comment: when you call your website, the server execute the public/index.php. This file creates the whole TYPO3 environment. And somewhere in this file config/system/settings.php is called.

Comment: if you want to mix your languages, it could be usefull to add .env to your installation. Then you could use these data in any contect. Here is an example:
https://blog.blue-side.de/2021/02/benutzung-von-env-in-typo3/